# Convergence of $\sum_{k \geq 1} e^{-tk} \cos kz$

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, trigonometry, convergence-divergence, exponential-function

I would like to find the convergence of the series $\sum_{k \geq 1} e^{-tk} \cos kz$. Clearly, this series converge in using the comparison test or the integral. How could I get an explicit function of this convergence? Is there anyone could give me a hint how to proceed?

Comment: Hint: 
$ |e^{-tk} cosk(x-y)| \le |e^{-kt}| $

Comment: Please, replace that $(x-y)$ with a simple $z$. My aversion for useless extra parameters is growing deeper and deeper :D

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio $y-x=u+v-w$. Clearly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $\cos kz = \mathrm{Re}(\cos kz + i \sin kz) = \mathrm{Re}(e^{ikz})$. Thus:

$$
\sum_{k \geq 1} e^{-tk} \cos kz = \sum_{k \geq 1} \mathrm{Re}(e^{-tk})\mathrm{Re}(e^{ikz}) = \sum_{k \geq 1} \mathrm{Re}(e^{k(-t + iz)}) = \mathrm{Re}\left(\sum_{k \geq 1} \left(e^{-t + iz}\right)^k\right)   
$$

which is a geometric series.

Comment: So the final answer is simply $\Re(\frac{-e^{-t+iz}}{e^{-t+iz}-1})$, right? Knowing that $\Re(-t+iz)=-t<1$, because $t>0$ in my problem. Could I simplify a bit more?